# Where is the screen saver folder

Tags: screen

I want to display my own screen saver. Where are the apple screen savers stored .
I looked in the hard drive and haven't found the folder

Comment: What exactly is an “apple screen saver”? Do you mean the Apple that makes Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ubuntu are you running? Screensavers are, by default, removed in 12.04, with a blank screen replacing them.

You could use nautilius or Dash to search for your files.  Apple screensavers aren't included officially in ubuntu releases.

Though please take this into consideration : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screensaver#Considerations

If you're running 12.04 and would rather use screensavers, then this may be of use to you: 
http://www.howtogeek.com/114027/